# I don't see icon on macOS system tray with the executable generated by pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller, system-tray, pyside6

I develop an application with an icon in the system tray of macOS but when I generate the executable with pyinstaller and I launch the application, the menu is well in the system tray but I do not see the icon, as if I had nothing.

I use PySide6 6.4.0.1, Python 3.10.7 and pyinstaller 5.6.1.
Here is the code for the system tray

```py
app = QApplication()
main_window = MainWindow()
if not QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable():
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'System Tray', 'System tray was not detected!')
    sys.exit(1)

app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

icon = QIcon('ressources/icon.jpg')

tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
tray.setIcon(icon)
tray.setVisible(True)

menu = QMenu()

action_hello = QAction('Hello World')
action_hello.triggered.connect(main_window.say_hello)
menu.addAction(action_hello)

action_exit = QAction('Exit')
action_exit.triggered.connect(app.exit)
menu.addAction(action_exit)

tray.setToolTip('Hello World app')
tray.setContextMenu(menu)
tray.show()

# Launch the app
app.exec()
```

Comment: Did you include the icon in the package?

Comment: @musicamante I think, yes, I run this command to get the executable : `pyinstaller hello.py --windowed --onefile --icon=ressources/icon.jpg`

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your help, I found a solution by searching how to add an icon in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeeded. I have found a part of the solution [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3327)!
It was necessary to add the icon in a resource file specific to Qt.
[Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) is a tutoriel to do that.
I have create a file *icon.qrc* :

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/">
   <file>ressources/icon.ico</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then, I have run the following commmand in cmd : `pyside6-rcc icons.qrc -o rc_icons.py`.
After, I
I imported the new file created *rc_icons.py* in *hello.py* : `import rc_icons.py`.
Finally, I have created my icon like this : `icon = QIcon(QPixmap(":/ressources/icon.ico"))`
Now, when I run the pyinstaller command and the executable, I see the icon on the system tray.